# cast complex query string to [fromQuery] model

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, query-string, json-deserialization, http-get

I Have [HttpGet] Method inside my  WebApi in DoNetCore project.
at the client Side i call this method with complex query string such as bellow

```
descending=false&page=1&rowsPerPage=20&Filters=%7B%22ProductId%22:14125F3D-3662-45DC-895C-691911A4767B%22%22%7D&Search=
```

and in contrller's action i have this endpoint:

```
    [HttpGet("GetPaginated")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> GetPaginated([FromQuery] BundleProductPaginatedRequest 
      model,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
     }
```

and BundleProductPaginatedRequest inherit this class that have ProductId inside that:

```
public  class PaginationRequest<T> where T : IAdvancedFilter?, new()
{
public int? Page { get; set; }
public int? RowsPerPage { get; set; }
public string? SortBy { get; set; }
public bool Descending { set; get; }
public string? Search { set; get; }
public T? Filters { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

i Know i can use [HttpPost] from complex method. but this action is [HttpGet] Method.
i also create custom model binder  to cast QueryString to dictionary and then to json and finaly to my model:
QueryString->Dictionary->Json->BundleProductPaginationrequest.
i know this is wrong way.
so please give me better solution

Comment: I think when you use `[FromQuery] Model m` as the input parameter, it should work for you. Do I misunderstand in some place?

Comment: as i understand. [fromQuery] in complex query String not work! please attention to my query string .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your requirement should be that your input request has parameter like `?xxx&Filter={"xx":"xxx"}&...`, it's in Json format but it's recognized as string, so it should be read as string, then try to convert to Json object.

[image]

=================================

[image]

======================================

I think it should work.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Hello")]
    public class HelloController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get([FromQuery]Movie mov)
        {
            var a = mov.Title;
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer dear! in this situation that's ok.but if you have property in your class that it is instance from a class what happen?

Comment: Sorry and I really ignored your `Filter` parameter. And in my test, I failed to find a way to get value from `&Filter={"xx":"xxx"}`, my idea is that you may change your request like what I showed in the screenshoot.

Comment: thanks dear friend!
that's ok but client side pass a json object to controller and [FromQuery] do not dispatch nested model

Comment: let's define `Filter` as `string` then try to convert it to a Json object, next we read the property. @MohsenEbrahimNezhad